# Framework7 react routing not working

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4, html-framework-7

I'm trying to build a mobile web app with react and framework7, but i don't seem to be able to figure out how the routing for framework7 works.

Below you can see the initialisation of the pagecontainer with the framework7 app:

```
export default class AbstractPage extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        initialized: false
    };

    const logger = createLogger();
    const reducer = combineReducers({ ...props.reducer, routing: routerReducer });
    this.history = createBrowserHistory();
    const historyMiddleware = routerMiddleware(this.history);
    this.store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(promise(), historyMiddleware, logger, thunkMiddleware));

    this.routes: [
        {path: '/', component: WallContainer},
        {path: '/create', component: CreateContainer},
    ];
}

render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={this.store}>
            <Router history={this.history}>
                <Framework7App themeType="material" routes={this.routes}>
                <Statusbar />
                <LeftPanel />
                <Views navbarThrough>
                    <View main url="/" dynamicNavbar>
                        <Pages>
                            <WallContainer />
                        </Pages>
                    </View>
                </Views>
            </Framework7App>
            </Router>
        </Provider>
    );
}
}
```

With the configuration from above, i always get the WallContainer rendered. When I click the link to got to the 'create' page, the url changes to localhost:3000/create, but the page doesn't change and the wallcontainer is still visible. Does anybody know what i'm doing wrong here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i forgot to add my framework7App context to my classes.

```
WallContainer.contextTypes = {
    framework7AppContext: PropTypes.object
};
```

When you don't add this context, you do not get a warning or exception, but the routing does not work.